# Multiple boxplots R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have two lists like this

```
head(x)

 [[1]] 30.0 28.9 28.9 
 [[2]] 29.4 29.4 29.4 
 [[3]] 27.2 28.3 
 [[4]] 27.8 30.0 27.2 28.3 28.9 28.3 27.8 

head(y)

 [[1]] 28.9 28.9 
 [[2]] 29.4 
 [[3]] 28.9 30.0 27.2 28.3 
 [[4]] 27.2 28.3 28.9 28.3 27.8
```

x and y have the same length but for each list entry ([[1]],[[2]]], etc.) the number of the elements can vary.

I can do box plots of x and y separately

```
boxplot(x)
boxplot(y)
```

but how can I do the box plot of their difference (for every list entry I have a mean, sd, etc and so for the differences of the means)?

Many thanks,

Comment: How are you defining "difference" here? And how are you drawing the boxplots of `x` and `y` separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your data looks like this

```
x<-list(
 c(30.0, 28.9, 28.9 ),
 c(29.4, 29.4, 29.4 ),
 c(27.2, 28.3 ),
 c(27.8, 30.0, 27.2, 28.3, 28.9, 28.3, 27.8 )
)

y<-list(
 c(28.9, 28.9 ),
 c(29.4 ),
 c(28.9, 30.0, 27.2, 28.3  ),
 c(27.2, 28.3, 28.9, 28.3, 27.8 )
)
```

Then you can make a box plot of the difference between the sets with

```
boxplot(mapply(function(x,y) {mean(x)-mean(y)}, x, y))
```

Of course this will only have one boxplot because each of the 4 groups will only have one difference in mean. The difference in means in the observed samples is a single value. It does not itself have a mean or a standard deviation. This is because you cannot calculate pair-wise difference in the lists because the vector of numbers in each set is different.